# Creating a 3D earth (sphere) with separate polygons for each country - can't turn vector of countries into sphere

Tags: vector

I am new to blender and am looking for a way to use a vector or a shapefile file with all the countries to create a 3D earth with all the countries separated into separate polygons.

I can Import the svg with the countries, but I haven't found a way to turn it into a sphere and keep the countries separate.

I can find a lot of tutorials to use an image as a texture to a UV sphere or manually deform it to a sphere.. But I can find no information how to proceed if after importing the vector I get a collection of vectors that need to be projected to a sphere while keeping the countries separate..

I found suggestions to join the vectors into 1 object - This is not what I need

Also, just an image with the countries and their borders visible is not enough, I need to have them as separate objects with information on which is which because I want the final sphere exported and imported to Godot where I need to be able to programmatically find each country.

Maybe my approach with the vectors is the problem?

Any help is appreciated

Thanks

Comment: You could subdivide the countries with a grid that you use as a Knife Project object. Then use a subdivided plane as Surface Deform object, make this plane spherical with 2 Simple Deform (Bend mode) modifiers?

Comment: @moonboots Thank you for the suggestion I'll deffinitely look into that. Could you maybe point me to an example of "subdivide the countries with a grid that you use as a Knife Project object" if I have a collection of vectors? Thanks!

Comment: You first need to convert your svg to mesh, then fill these meshes, then check Knife Project tool, if you project a grid it will allow you to subdivide your meshes so that you'll be able to bend them